# Google Play Integrity API Scope

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I need to use Google Play Integrity API

I am trying to use the scope provided in the documentation here - https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1.PlayIntegrityService.Scope.html

But I receive this error - *The service playintegrity has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. Request had insufficient authentication scopes.*

When I try to open the link itself I get this message:
*You are receiving this error either because your input OAuth2 scope name is invalid or it refers to a newer scope that is outside the domain of this legacy API.

This API was built at a time when the scope name format was not yet standardized. This is no longer the case and all valid scope names (both old and new) are catalogued at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes. Use that webpage to lookup (manually) the scope name associated with the API you are trying to call and use it to craft your OAuth2 request.*

When I try to search for it in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes. I cannot find it, I would think it might have been discontinued but there seems to be recent development on this API according to GitHub. https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client.

The API is enabled in google cloud on the project.
I've also tried adding it to the Google OAuth Screen Scopes but it also doesn't show up as a possible option.
[image: OAuth Consent screen]

The code used when trying to access this API:

```
UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "x",
                ClientSecret = "y"
            },
            new [] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/playintegrity"},
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
        );
         

        var service = new PlayIntegrityService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            ApplicationName = "Test",
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });

        // Create the DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest body with your nonce as the IntegrityToken.
        DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest requestBody = new DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest()
        {
            IntegrityToken = nonce.ToString()
        };

        // The package name of the app.
        string packageName = "Test";

        // Create the DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest.
        V1Resource.DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest request = new V1Resource.DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest(service, requestBody, packageName);

        // Execute the request and get the response.
        DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse response = await request.ExecuteAsync();

        // Now, response.TokenPayloadExternal contains the decoded integrity payload.
        TokenPayloadExternal payload = response.TokenPayloadExternal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code works (C#, NetFramework) and Google Cloud

1. "Create a service account within the Google Cloud project that's linked to your app. During this account creation process, you need to grant your service account the roles of Service Account User and Service Usage Consumer.". Just create one and assign the 2 roles in Google Cloud
2. Create in the account a Key (type JSON) and download the .json
3. Go to your project, add Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1
4. Code for invoke

```
public TokenPayloadExternal Decrypt()
{
    var theGoogleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromJson({ JsonCredentials});

    var theInitializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = theGoogleCredential,
        ApplicationName = { ApplicationName }
    };
    var theRequest = new DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest()
    {
        IntegrityToken = { Attestation }
    };
    var theService = new PlayIntegrityService(theInitializer);
    var theResult = theService.V1.DecodeIntegrityToken(theRequest, { ApkPackageName});

    return theResult.Execute().TokenPayloadExternal;
}
```

JsonCredentials is the .json